# sudo very slow after winbind to AD on RHEL6

Tags: linux, samba

When I run a sudo command after binding my linux machine to an AD domain using samba/winbind, it takes anywhere between 10 seconds and 2 minutes to respond before prompting for my password.

I've checked my /etc/resolv.conf and DNS seems to be set up properly. Commands like dig run without a hitch so I am assuming the problem must not be related to DNS. As per other posts, I've also made sure both my hostname and FQDN are listed in /etc/hosts for loopback.

I set my winbind log level to 10 and checked the logs. I don't know what does and doesn't matter but some things I noticed in the logs:

```
[2013/06/05 10:05:19.481689,  1] ../librpc/ndr/ndr.c:284(ndr_print_function_debug)
   wbint_LookupName: struct wbint_LookupName
      in: struct wbint_LookupName
          domain                   : *
              domain                   : 'MYDOMAIN'
          name                     : *
              name                     : 'ROOT'
          flags                    : 0x00000008 (8)
[2013/06/05 10:05:19.481857,  1] ../librpc/ndr/ndr.c:284(ndr_print_function_debug)
   wbint_LookupName: struct wbint_LookupName
      out: struct wbint_LookupName
          type                     : *
              type                     : SID_NAME_USE_NONE (0)
          sid                      : *
              sid                      : S-0-0
          result                   : NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
[2013/06/05 10:05:19.482076,  5] winbindd/winbindd_getgroups.c:186(winbindd_getgroups_recv)
  Could not convert sid S-0-0: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
[2013/06/05 10:05:19.482121, 10] winbindd/winbindd.c:679(wb_request_done)
  wb_request_done[3787:GETGROUPS]: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
```

It seems to be trying to look up the user ROOT in the domain, which obviously shouldn't be happening... Could this be the root of the cause? If so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely would do that,  Make sure you have

```
passwd       files ldap
group        files ldap
shadow       files ldap
```

in nsswitch.conf.  Every system call that requires elevated
privileges will otherwise be slow as molasses.

Comment: I was sure this would be it but no. My nsswitch.conf already has:

passwd:     files winbind
shadow:     files winbind
group:      files winbind

Comment: Hmmm ... next thought: you have NSCD running, and it wasn't restarted after the change?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will help, but do you have a `username map` file that contains:

```
root = administrator
nobody = guest
```

and a global parameter in smb.conf pointing to it, such as

`username map = /etc/samba/smbusers`

as well as the global parameter

`map to guest = bad user`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
winbind enum users = no
winbind enum groups = no
winbind nested groups = false
```

to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, in section `[global]`

Note: this disables nested groups

Answer (score 0):

Old issue but this looks very similar.
I had such an issue and it turned out I had added a VPN interface (wireguard) to the `interfaces` list of my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` SAMBA configuration.

Removing this line even without restarting any service fixed the more than 20 seconds it took for sudo/su/etc to give me a prompt.
I believe this was samba-dcerpcd taking ages to start rpcd_lsad when so.